# Break list into rows while preserving identifiers in r

Tags: regex, r, list, reshape

I'm working with the following type of dataset

```
    names<-c("Aname","Aname","Bname","Cname","Cname")
    list <- list( c('a, b','b, r','c, g'), c('d,g','e,j'),
    c('d, h','s, q','f,q'), c('d,r ','s, z'),c('d, r','d, r'))
    data<-cbind(names, list)
```

And want to break out each element of a list and then bind it with the "name" variable. So the dataset I'm trying to produce would look like this:

```
Column 1   Column 2
Aname      a
Aname      b
Aname      b
Aname      r
Aname      c
```

There have been many discussions of how to convert a list to a data.frame, but I'm struggling to find any advice about how to do this "within" a dataframe where I'd like to preserve identifiers on the same row as the list (in this case Names). Many thanks!

Comment: Please don't call anything `names` or `list`; these are already the names of commonly-used functions.

Comment: @Frank,  but so are `data` and `df` and I don't see a lot of people complaining about that. Truth is that in most cases, only legibility is impaired, not functionality....

Answer (score 7):

You could use `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
melt(lapply(setNames(list, names), function(x)
                      unlist(strsplit(x, ', | |,'))))
```

Comment: @Tim it works because "|" means "or". But what if the last entry was  `d ,     r`  instead? This would produce additional unwanted entries whose value is a single space character, right?

Comment: Oh, just realized this is the same as the answer I just added. With base R, use `stack` in place of `melt` for the same result (with different column names).

Comment: @konvas  I didn't try all the possible cases.  Thanks

Comment: @Frank It's okay.   `stack` would give some more options to the OP

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible base R solution

```
myFunc <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), ", | |,"))

data.frame(Col1 = rep(names, sapply(list, function(x) length(myFunc(x)))), 
           Col2 = myFunc(list))

#     Col1 Col2
# 1  Aname    a
# 2  Aname    b
# 3  Aname    b
# 4  Aname    r
# 5  Aname    c
# 6  Aname    g
# 7  Aname    d
# 8  Aname    g
# 9  Aname    e
# 10 Aname    j
# 11 Bname    d
# 12 Bname    h
# 13 Bname    s
# 14 Bname    q
# 15 Bname    f
# 16 Bname    q
# 17 Cname    d
# 18 Cname    r
# 19 Cname    s
# 20 Cname    z
# 21 Cname    d
# 22 Cname    r
# 23 Cname    d
# 24 Cname    r
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm getting and "arguments imply differing number of rows" error with my "real" data- I think it may be related to the way the list is indexed. In data view one line looks like this: list(c("our", "booth"), c("booth", "at"), c("at", "volunteer"), c("volunteer", "day")). Any ideas? Apologies, I'm a bit of a noob.

Comment: Many thanks, David. Unfortunately I'm still getting an error: Error in strsplit(unlist(x), ", | |,") : non-character argument. I must have some type of strange data in one of my lists. These are bigrams created from a character vector... they should all be characters. Might it be referring to some other type of punctuation mark?

Comment: Try changing `unlist(x)` to `as.character(unlist(x))` maybe

Answer (score 4):

One more approach with `splitstackshape` - its `cSplit` function strips whitespace adjacent to the delimiter by default.

```
library(splitstackshape)
lengths <- sapply(data[, 2], length)
nameslist <- unlist(rep(data[, 1], lengths))
df1 <- data.frame(names = nameslist, chars = unlist(data[, 2]))
cSplit(df1, "chars", sep = ",", direction = "long")
```

Or per Ananda's comment, simply:

```
cSplit(data.table(names = data[, "names"], list = sapply(data[, "list"], toString)),
 "list", ",", "long")
```

Result:

```
    names chars
 1: Aname     a
 2: Aname     b
 3: Aname     b
 4: Aname     r
 5: Aname     c
 6: Aname     g
 7: Aname     d
 8: Aname     g
 9: Aname     e
10: Aname     j
11: Bname     d
12: Bname     h
13: Bname     s
14: Bname     q
15: Bname     f
16: Bname     q
17: Cname     d
18: Cname     r
19: Cname     s
20: Cname     z
21: Cname     d
22: Cname     r
23: Cname     d
24: Cname     r
```

If you don't want the result as a `data.table`, you can wrap the last line in `as.data.frame()`.

Comment: I'd personally do `cSplit(data.table(names = data[, "names"], list = sapply(data[, "list"], toString)), "list", ",", "long")`, but +1

Comment: @Ananda that is an elegant solution, short and easy to follow.  I've added it to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Another variation: `cSplit(stack(setNames(data[, 2], data[, 1])), "values", ",", "long")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with dplyr/tidyr. The idea is to convert each element of `list` to a list itself (from a character vector, which it is currently) and then call the very useful `unnest` function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(data) %>% 
    unnest(list) %>% 
    mutate(list = strsplit(list, ",")) %>%
    unnest(list)
#   names list
#1  Aname    a
#2  Aname    b
#3  Aname    b
#4  Aname    r
#5  Aname    c
#6  Aname    g
#7  Aname    d
#8  Aname    g
#9  Aname    e
#10 Aname    j
#11 Bname    d
#12 Bname    h
#13 Bname    s
#14 Bname    q
#15 Bname    f
#16 Bname    q
#17 Cname    d
#18 Cname   r 
#19 Cname    s
#20 Cname    z
#21 Cname    d
#22 Cname    r
#23 Cname    d
#24 Cname    r
```

(To get rid of extra spaces, if needed, you can append`%>% mutate(list = gsub(" ", "", list))` to the chain of commands.)

Comment: Thanks very much. When I run this on my real data I'm getting the following error: "Error: Columns are not all same length" any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: I don't recall seeing this error, I imagine it's thrown by `unnest`. Could you unchain the commands and run them one by one, and let me know at which stage this error is produced?

Answer (score 2):

The OP lumps two questions together.

The answer to the first is to clean the data. For example, copying @DavidArenburg's function:

```
myFunc <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), ", | |,")) 
clean  <- sapply(list, myFunc)
```

And the second step is to stack:

```
stack(setNames(clean,names))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this assigns each string within the list, but not each element in the list). Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @ChrisBail I don't know the difference between those two things. No need to explain if one of the other answers works for you; you can just click the checkmark by that answer. If none of them work, maybe you need to edit your question to clarify and/or change the example data.